# Android 2.3.3 NFC peer-to-peer communication with PC based NFC reader

Tags: android, nfc

I need to implement a demo which involves NFC peer-to-peer communication between a Nexus S (android 2.3.3) and a Windows based desktop PC.

My understanding is that the Nexus S along with android 2.3.3 can send and receive NDEF Push Messages (and I'm sure it works, although I haven't tested it).

My requirement is that the other end is a PC based application. So the questions are
1. has anybody tried this ? any success ?
2. is there a recommended a USB based NFC reader that I can use ? I know there are many in the market, but as I don't have the privilege of time and money, I would appreciate if you can suggest a device that work for sure
3. is there an SDK for the device that supports Push Messages?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Check http://www.grundid.de/nfc.

Comment: Did you succeed? The Applet example is so long ago, no java could run it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an ACR122 NFC reader for this purpose and it's working fine. It cost around 8k.

Comment: 8k of what? EUR? USD? <indian currency>? A quick google search showed something around 100 EUR.